# Missing AdActivity when using Google Services

Tags: android, service, admob, ads

I am using admob on an app of mine and I want to migrate to new google servives sdk cause I want to use Leaderboards too. The problem is that I want my app to be compatible with android 2.3 that has about 20% of my users. 
The example of google shows that I have to put inside the AndroidManifest the snipet

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|‌​screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

if I use this and set the android target to 14 everything is fine, if I set the target to 8 to support my legacy customers it does not compile cause before sdk 9 screenSize|smallestScreenSize is not supported but if I remove it the app does not show ads and I get an error message that I need AdActivity with android:configChanges is missing 
The snipet that I use is

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode"/>
```

Has anyone managed to use the ad service with older android sdk ?

Comment: what do you mean do this by code? This is AndroidManifest things, it cannot be done by code

Answer (score 0):

sdkVersion=8 is Froyo
sdkVersion=9 is Gingerbread (ie 2.3)

So set the minSdkVersion="9"

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs, maybe you'll see problems with view size. Also you may have problems with ad setting (region, age, ect).